# Java Stored Procedure DB2 issue

Tags: java, db2, java-stored-procedures

In my class I have created simple method below. This class also has a main function in it. I am calling getRes() from my DB2 stored proc.

```java
public static void getRes() {
   System.out.println("Start");
   try{  
       Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");  
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(  
       "jdbc:db2://url:50003/DB","user","Password");  
       Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
       stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO schema.TEST(ID) VALUES(1)"); 
   } catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println(e);
   } finally {
       if(con!=null) {
           try {
               con.close();
           } catch (SQLException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   System.out.println("End");
}
```

I am calling this function from DB2 stored proc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.sp_TEST1()
 FENCED
 MODIFIES SQL DATA
EXTERNAL NAME 'connection.Connect.getRes()'
LANGUAGE JAVA
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA;
```

```
call schema.sp_TEST1()
```

This stored procedure is getting executed successfully. But I doubt my method is executed or not. Because there is no entry made in the test table after execution.

Below are the steps I have followed to deploy this jar file.
1. Exported the jar from Eclipse. Verified if the jar is working fine.
2. Executed call sqlj.install_jar(). Verified the installation in SYSIBM.SYSJARCONTENTS.
3. SET the class path on db server 
 export CLASSPATH=/home/db2inse5/sqllib/function/jar/SchemaName/JarName.jar
4.created the sp and called the sp.

Expected output is an entry made in table test.
But I am not getting the expected result though the sp execution is successful.

Updated-20200423
I tried committing the database connection part and replaced it with a file creation in db server. This worked so I can confirm that the jar was correctly called from the SP and jar file worked correctly. But the above part is not resolved yet

```
public static void getRes() {
    System.out.println("Start");
            File myObj = new File("/opt/filename.txt");
            myObj.createNewFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong method of getting a `Connection` object in a `Parameter style Java` routine. Please read the following topic in the documentation: [Parameter style JAVA procedures](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0023926.html).
You must not get it as in an ordinal jdbc application. Don't use the `Class.forName` call. Use the following instead:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
```

Read about [Restrictions on external routines](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0009198.html) as well. Don't use `System.out.println(...)` inside a Java routine.

## Examle

Do this as is on the database server from the db2 instance owner without any modifications. Create the directory structure mentioned. Be sure, that db2profile is sourced in your session.

ExecAny.java:

```
package ru.ibm.db2udf;

import com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Diagnosable;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class ExecAny 
{
  /*
  --SQL statement for the class file placement w/o jar:
  --${DB2_HOME}/function/ru/ibm/db2udf/ExecAny.class

  --Uncomment the commented out line instead
  --if you placed this class into jar file and deployed it.

  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXEC_ANY 
  (
    SQL VARCHAR(4000)
  , LOG VARCHAR(512) DEFAULT NULL
  )
  LANGUAGE Java
  EXTERNAL NAME 'ru.ibm.db2udf.ExecAny.exec'
  --EXTERNAL NAME 'EXEC_ANY:ru.ibm.db2udf.ExecAny.exec'
  FENCED THREADSAFE
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA;

  Usage:
    call exec_any('declare global temporary table test(i int) on commit preserve rows not logged', '/tmp/exec_any.txt');
    call exec_any('insert into session.test values 1', '/tmp/exec_any.txt');
    -- W/o logging
    call exec_any('insert into session.test values 2');

    select * from session.test;
  */
  public static void exec (String sql, String logfile) throws Exception 
  {
    Logger logger = null;
    FileHandler fhdl = null;
    Connection con = null;
    CallableStatement cst = null;
    try 
    {
      if (logfile != null && ! "".equals((logfile=logfile.trim())))
      {
        logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        fhdl = new FileHandler(logfile, true);
        fhdl.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        logger.addHandler(fhdl);
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        logger.info("***");
      }
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
      con.setAutoCommit(false);
      if (logger != null) logger.info("Trying to prepare: " + sql);
      cst = con.prepareCall(sql);
      if (logger != null) logger.info("Prepared: " + sql);
      cst.execute();
      if (logger != null) logger.info("Executed: " + sql);
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
      if (logger != null) 
      {
        while (ex != null) 
        {
          if (ex instanceof DB2Diagnosable) 
          {
            DB2Diagnosable db2ex = (DB2Diagnosable) ex;
            com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Sqlca sqlca = db2ex.getSqlca();
            if (sqlca != null) 
              logger.severe("\nSQLCODE: " + sqlca.getSqlCode() + "\nMESSAGE: " + sqlca.getMessage());
            else 
              logger.severe("\nError code: " + ex.getErrorCode() + "\nError msg : " + ex.getMessage());
          } 
          else 
            logger.severe("\nError code (no db2): " + ex.getErrorCode() + "\nError msg  (no db2): " + ex.getMessage());
          logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
          ex = ex.getNextException();
        }
      }
    } 
    finally
    {
      if (fhdl != null) {fhdl.close(); fhdl = null;}
      if (cst != null) {cst.close(); cst = null;}
      if (con != null) {con.close(); con = null;}
    }
  }

}
```

Instruction on how to build and deploy it:

```
# Suppose we are on a Db2 server and !!!db2profile is sourced in the session!!!
# java sources are in source
# java classes are in classes

$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x classes
drwxr-xr-x source
drwxr-xr-x sql

$ find source -name '*.java'
source/ru/ibm/db2udf/ExecAny.java

# Compile
$ (cd source; ${DB2_HOME}/java/jdk64/bin/javac -d ../classes ru/ibm/db2udf/ExecAny.java)
# Create jar
$ ${DB2_HOME}/java/jdk64/bin/jar cvf exec_any.jar -C classes ru/ibm/db2udf/ExecAny.class

# Deploy jar
$ db2 connect to mydb
#$ db2 "call sqlj.replace_jar('file:${PWD}/exec_any.jar', 'EXEC_ANY')"
$ db2 "call sqlj.install_jar('file:${PWD}/exec_any.jar', 'EXEC_ANY')"
$ db2 "call sqlj.refresh_classes()"

# Jar file must appear in the ${DB2_HOME}/function/jar directory
$ find ${DB2_HOME}/function/jar -name '*.jar'
.../sqllib/function/jar/<USER_NAME>/EXEC_ANY.jar

# SP CREATE and CALL commands
$ cat sql/exec_any.sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXEC_ANY
(
  SQL VARCHAR(4000)
, LOG VARCHAR(512) DEFAULT NULL
)
LANGUAGE Java
EXTERNAL NAME 'EXEC_ANY:ru.ibm.db2udf.ExecAny.exec'
FENCED THREADSAFE
MODIFIES SQL DATA
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA;

(=
-- W/ logging to some file accessible by the db2 instance fenced user on the server
-- $ stat -c "%U" ${DB2_HOME}/ctrl/.fencedID
call exec_any('declare global temporary table test(i int) on commit preserve rows not logged', '/tmp/exec_any.txt');
call exec_any('insert into session.test values 1', '/tmp/exec_any.txt');
-- W/o logging
call exec_any('insert into session.test values 2');
select * from session.test;
=)
```

Comment: Tried this. Still same issue

Comment: Have you called `CALL SQLJ.REFRESH_CLASSES()` after the jar redeployment as described in [Modifications to external routine library and class files](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0023746.html)?  If yes, and you still get some unanticipated behavior, then try to log all the routine execution to some file on the server.

Comment: You might want also to consider issuing an explicit commit on the connection before closing it.

Comment: @mustaccio I will try that. Though wen I run java method using cmd. The data is reflected in db

Comment: Try to remove `catch` block and all attempts to print an exception. Add `throws Exception` to the method definition. This allows you get some info on possible error to db2diag.log. Call `db2diag -H 1m -o mydiag.txt` (1 min history from the db2diag.log file) on the server after calling your routine. What do you get in the txt file?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I am trying to command db2diag commands on linux path /home/db2inse5/sqllib/db2dump but this command is not recognizd

Comment: You must source a db2profile in your session with the `. /home/db2inse5/sqllib/db2profile` call to have an ability to run db2 commands / utilities. I assume, that the `db2inse5` instance is your db2 server instance running your database.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I have updated the question. Seems like jar file was installed correctly and the call to the jar was successful. But the db connection code didnt work it seems

Comment: @Akashpokharkar I've updated my answer with the example & instruction.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I have logged the exception in a file. The exception says 'No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2://URL:50003/DB'